# Fetch path of the photo saved in ios photo library

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary, alassetlibrary

I already know how to access photo library with uiimageviewcontroller, select the photo, convert it into data and save it to documents directory.

However this does not give me the path of the photo where it is stored in ios photo library.
Kindly help me How can I get the path of the photo stored in ios photo library.

Comment: give a code for save photo

Comment: It won't. When you access or save a photo, you don't need a path. So why do you need to know the actual path of photo saved?

Comment: Because rather than copying the photos in my application's documents directory which will increase my app size gradually, i simply want to save the path in my database table so that i can simply show the photo via that path

Comment: Photos in iOS does not have path/name by which you can uniquely identify them..

Comment: @Bugivore..As android has the option of external store sd card so path is easily retrieved. As Ios does not have external storage, but even internal path of ios Photo library is not possible?

Comment: have a look at AlAsset, AlAsssetRepresentation and its propery URL.         https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Alok..Yes I am able to fetch the path URL with the help of info dictionary returned in delegate method of UIImagePickerViewController.